# Can't set 1280x800 screen resolution on Dell Inspiron 1501 laptop under Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: lubuntu, dell, display-resolution, amd-graphics, inspiron

I managed to install Lubuntu 18.04 on Dell Inspiron 1501 with "nomodeset" grub setting and make WiFi card work, but I can't set screen resolution to anything except 1024x768. Native screen resolution is 1280x800.
I am able to add 1280x800_60.00 mode to the list with xrandr. But when I try to enable it, xrandr says "screen cannot be larger than 1024x768 (desired size 1280x800)".

I suspect that I use some kind of default VESA VGA video driver as a result of my "nomodeset" setting, but not sure if this is the root cause.

Laptop has ATI 1150 graphic card, but lspci sees it as "RS482M Mobility Radeon Xpress 200"

Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: "Laptop has ATI 1150 graphic card, but lspci sees it as "RS482M Mobility Radeon Xpress 200"" those are fundamentally the same. What graphics driver is active? That is the one that will set the different resolutions.

Comment: With "nomodeset" lshw -c video doesn't show any "driver" at all. Without "nomodeset" it shows "radeon".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing "nomodeset" from grub command line surprisingly fixed the problem without breaking Lubuntu load process in most cases.
In some cases loading Lubuntu without "nomodeset" flag ends up with coloured stripes on display, but restart helps.